# ORA-01722: invalid number intermittently

Tags: oracle, ora-01722

We have a SQL query which has a condition like below.

result_value <>  0

The result_value is a varchar column in our Oracle EBS database. The query works fine most of the time. But randomly it throws this below error.

[Error] Execution (216: 33): ORA-01722: invalid number

Changing the condition result_value <> TO_CHAR ('0') makes it work when it errors out.

Any reason why the system behaves like this?  Below is a screenshot of the result. The alphanumeric column is a result of regexp_like(result_value , '^-?\d+(.\d+)?$(E(+|-)\d+)?$')
then 'numeric'
else 'alpha'
end alphanumeric

[image]

Comment: Likely you are suffering with implicit casting problem. `result_value <> 0` the db automatically tries to convert the content of `result_value` to number the problem is as your result shows it might be that some of those values in `result_value` column might have a hidden character as a space or something else that is resulting your expression to give you "alpha" for those numbers.

Comment: This is expected. If result_value is a varchar, you should be looking for '0' and not 0. It can give intermittent results depending on the join order and predicate apply order as the plan changes. For example, one predicate could filter out rows that have a non-numeric in that field before the result_value predicate is applied, and so you get no error. A different plan might reverse that, and you get an error. Also, the database might apply the conversion to the column rather than your constant, or the other-way-round. As the plan changes, a gremlin like this can pop up.  So kill the gremlin.

Comment: @PaulW `result_value <> '0'` would not match `0E0` or `0.0`.

Comment: @MT0, it is unlikely there are multiple versions of representing 0 created by a single program that loads this table. Whatever character or string represents no money should be excluded as a string. The only need for conversion is if it truly is unpredictable in its format. I assume from the lack of a decimal in -50 that a 0 would be simply 0. If that's not the case OP should filter out whatever it is.

Answer (score 1):

From Oracle 12, you can use `TO_NUMBER(result_value DEFAULT NULL ON CONVERSION ERROR)` and then you can compare to a number and may not need the regular expression:

```sql
SELECT result_value
FROM   table_name
WHERE  TO_NUMBER(result_value DEFAULT NULL ON CONVERSION ERROR) <> 0
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (result_value) AS
SELECT '0' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '0E0' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '0.0' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '0E+0' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '0.0E-1234' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABC' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| RESULT_VALUE |
| --- |
| 1 |

*Note: using `result_value <> '0'` would only exclude one of row of the sample data when there are actually 5 rows with the numeric value identical to `0`.*

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/XuZvhR_b)